# Error converting data type varchar to numeric for this below query

Tags: sql-server

Error converting data type varchar to numeric for this below query

Please suggest what can i modify to fix

```
    Update BUDTANKS
 set    BUDTANKS.SHELLCAPACITY = 0.0000000 --Numeric Column
       ,BUDTANKS.WORKINGCAPACITY =  0.0000000 --Numeric Column
       ,BUDTANKS.LEASEDCAPACITY = 0.0000000 --Numeric Column
       ,BUDTANKS.VERSIONID = 1
       ,BUDTANKS.STATUSID = 1
       ,BUDTANKS.IMPORTEDRECORD = 1
       ,BUDTANKS.LastModifiedUserID = 'Import'
       ,BUDTANKS.LASTMODIFIEDDATETIME = GETDATE()
FROM BUDTANKS BTANK WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BUDTERMINALS BT WITH(NOLOCK) ON BT.TERMINALID = BTANK.TERMINALID 
INNER JOIN External_Liq_Itm_Tanks ELIT WITH(NOLOCK) ON ELIT.TerminalName = BT.MBFTERMINALNAME AND ELIT.TankName = BTANK.TANKNAME
Where   (ISNULL(BTANK.SHELLCAPACITY, '') <> ISNULL(0.0000000, '')
     OR ISNULL(BTANK.WORKINGCAPACITY, '') <> ISNULL(0.0000000, '')
     OR ISNULL(BTANK.LEASEDCAPACITY, '') <> ISNULL(0.0000000, '')
     OR (BTANK.STATUSID <> 1)
     OR (BTANK.IMPORTEDRECORD <> 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem with this query is in the `Where` condition:

```
Where   (ISNULL(BTANK.SHELLCAPACITY, '') <> ISNULL(0.0000000, '')
     OR ISNULL(BTANK.WORKINGCAPACITY, '') <> ISNULL(0.0000000, '')
     OR ISNULL(BTANK.LEASEDCAPACITY, '') <> ISNULL(0.0000000, '')
     OR (BTANK.STATUSID <> 1)
     OR (BTANK.IMPORTEDRECORD <> 1))
```

You need to change it to:

```
Where   (ISNULL(BTANK.SHELLCAPACITY, 0) <> 0)
     OR ISNULL(BTANK.WORKINGCAPACITY,0) <> 0)
     OR ISNULL(BTANK.LEASEDCAPACITY, 0) <> 0)
     OR (BTANK.STATUSID <> 1)
     OR (BTANK.IMPORTEDRECORD <> 1))
```

or

```
 Where  BTANK.SHELLCAPACITY Is Not Null
         OR BTANK.WORKINGCAPACITY Is Not Null
         OR BTANK.LEASEDCAPACITY Is Not Null
         OR (BTANK.STATUSID <> 1)
         OR (BTANK.IMPORTEDRECORD <> 1))
```